# AngularJs condition class And regular class

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, ng-class

here is the problem, I need to apply a conditional class (add 'card--done' class if completed is true), and, also add the class stored in task.color.

Here's the code:

```
        <!-- Card -->
        <div class="card" 
            ng-repeat="task in projectsData[currentProject].tasks track by $id(task)"
            ng-class="{'card--done': task.completed}, task.color">
        </div><!-- End of card -->
```

I tried pretty much everything i could think of, but nothing worked for combining those.

I also tried a function, still won't work.

```
ng-class="[getClasses(), {'card--done': task.completed}]"
```

Spent an hour and a half on this, please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do like this :

```
ng-class="[(task.completed && 'card--done') , task.color]"
```

if `task.completed` is falsy it will add class name "false" to the element but it should be harmless. Problem is when you provide an array it will use the string representation of every item in the array, so using an object will just show `[Object object]`, unless you evaluate the object with bracket notation like:

```
 ng-class="[{true: 'card--done'}[task.completed], task.color]"
 //ng-class="[getClasses(), {true: 'card--done'}[task.completed]]"
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/biVpvD?p=preview)**

Comment: Awesome ! 
That works, if I may ask though, where do the parenthesis comes from? I'd like to understand how this works.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: no, sorry, bad English, I meant those: "()". 
Never saw it used outside of function parameters in js.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use condition and value from model in ng-class.

Here is what I tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/walvekarnikhil/jLku2s0c/

```
<div class="card" 
        ng-repeat="task in tasks"
        ng-class="[task.color,task.status]">
            <h2>{{ task.name }} </h2>                
</div>

var tasks = [ {name:'A',status:'pending',color:'card-red'},
             {name:'B', status:'complete',color:'card-yellow'},
             {name:'C', status:'started',color:'card-blue'}];
```

I have added status as attribute to task and added CSS for those status.